# Convert a value from cm to inch in excel

Tags: excel, vba

A number in centimeter format can be converted to inch using this function:

```
=CONVERT(A1,"cm","in")
```

What i want is that instead of replacing the number, putting the converted number next to original one. Actually it's a more complicated situation:

Original cell:

```
35 - 45 cm
```

After convertion (all in one cell):

```
35 - 45 cm
(14 - 18 inch)
```

So, how to do this in excel in an automated way since there are many cells in this format, maybe using a macro?

Comment: Have you tried some macro code we could use as a starting point?

Comment: No. I have no experience with macros.

Comment: @Adige72: Since you are updating the same cell you will have to use a macro. Record a macro and then amend that macro. I would recommend giving it a try an then posting the code here with the error mesasage that you are getting so that we can take it from there.

Comment: Your original Convert function will fail as you can't convert spaces, dashed or letters from cm to in. Will your cell ALWAYS be EVERYTIME without fail a 2 digit number then a space a dash a space another 2 digit value a space and the letters cm??

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will start with this but I Suggest providing me more information so I can better Solve your problem:

```
Sub AddConversionToCell()

    FirstNumberAsIn = WorksheetFunction.Convert(Left(Range("A1").Value, 2), "cm", "in")
    SecondNumberAsIn = WorksheetFunction.Convert(Mid(Range("A1").Value, 6, 2), "cm", "in")
    Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value & " ( " & FirstNumberAsIn & " - " & SecondNumberAsIn & " inch)"

End Sub
```

Comment: I had problems with windows. So let me try it after reinstall the OS. But trusting my code interpretation, it seems ok to me.

Comment: This causes an infinite loop, changing the cell after and after. There should be an if statement to make this run for once, right? For instance wrapping your function (`Sub` means function or something?) with `if cell content does not include the word inch` So how to do this in VBA?

Comment: IF you are running this on a Worksheet event and that is what is causing the loop, Add Application.EnableEvents = false then Application.EnableEvents = true before and after the code block that calls my sub.

Answer (score 1):

Formula approach - if your values start in A1 then place this in B1 and fill down.

```
= A1 & CHAR(10) & "(" & ROUND(CONVERT(
VALUE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("-",A1)-1)),"cm","in"),1) & " - " &
ROUND(CONVERT(
VALUE(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"cm",""), SEARCH("-",A1)+1,10)),"cm","in"),1) & "in)"
```

Comment: He wants the converted values in the same cell as the original values not in a separate cell.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "he" can manage a copy-paste values step.  Did you really down-vote my answer just for that?